# Avoid duplicate data in mySQL table

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table in my DDBB:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id, subject)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

This is an example of my table:

```
id  | subject |
1       test        
2       ICT         
3       ICT
```

The key (id) is not duplicate since it is automatically generated by MySQL, but the las two rows are repeating.

How can I avoid repeating the subject name?

I have read that it can be done with a 'constraint' like this:

```
ALTER TABLE subjects
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_subject UNIQUE KEY(subject);
```

But I've tried it and I get an error every time.

I know that this has been asked before but I'm still entering from my PHP, some subjects with the same name and the program always lets me enter them.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the constraint gives you an error because it wouldn't be satisfied since you already have duplicated data.

You have to delete the duplicates and then add the constraint, which would then work.

If you want to select only distinct rows right now, even when having duplicates in your database, you can run the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    subjects AS s1
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            subjects AS s2
        WHERE
            s1.subject = s2.subject
        AND s1.id != s2.id
    );
```

Or

```
SELECT
    s1.*
FROM
    subjects AS s1
LEFT JOIN
    subjects AS s2
    ON (s1.subject = s2.subject AND s1.id != s2.id)
WHERE 
    s2.id IS NULL
```

Both will give the same result but I find the first one to be more explicit about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `AND s1.id != s2.subject` is a typo I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answerAntoine! I have tried your code but it shows only the subjects that are not repeated. That's fine?

Comment: Yes, this is the point of my query. If you want only the duplicates, then change `NOT EXISTS` to `EXISTS`.

Comment: Yes, it works perfect :D, but how can I show the ones that are not duplicate and only one of the duplicates subjects?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an index on a column of data type `TEXT` because that's too long for an index.

You can create an index, even a unique index, on a *prefix* of that column.

```
ALTER TABLE subjects
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_subject UNIQUE KEY(subject(191));
```

This means two subjects cannot have exactly the same leading 191 characters.

I don't think you should declare the PRIMARY KEY including the subject. It's more typical to use the auto-increment integer column alone as the primary key.

So your table ends up with this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `constraint_subject` (`subject`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I chose the length 191 because it's the longest I could fit in the 767 byte limit that InnoDB has on indexes (utf8mb4 characters count as 4 bytes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bill! I've tried what you said but I'm getting this alert in Mysql: `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '' for key 'constraint_subjects'`. Do you know why this is happening? I've also dropped the primary key from `subject` as you suggested

Comment: It's happening because you have two or more rows with `''` as the subject. In other words, they are duplicates. You can't create a UNIQUE KEY constraint when your data contains duplicates. To fix this, either give each row a distinct value, or else set them to NULL, because UNIQUE KEY ignores NULLs.